# R Markdown not showing execute button for other engines

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

In R Markdown if I have a chunk coded with the normal r chunk wrappers,

````
```{r}
[R code]
```
````

A play button will appear. However, when I run a chunk wrapped like so for other language engines:

````
```{python}
[python code]
```
````

or replacing python replaced with bash/sh, I don't get a play button on the right.

Is there a package I need to install? I restarted Rstudio, and even downloaded the Lesson 5: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-5.html , which even shows those play buttons, and I still don't get it. I am on a mac, and saw that someone on a Windows computer was able to see the play buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to install the package "knitr". Try to check that first.

Second, you might need to state explitly where your interpreter for Python is, for instance. Use

`{python, engine.path = '/usr/bin/python3'}
YOUR CODE`

to see if it works.

Comment: I have knitr downloaded, but it seems to be an Rstudio issue. I'm going to redownload it

Comment: apparently it was a setting on Rmarkdown, Show output inline for all Rmarkdown documents. thanks!